# set relation grocery crud error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, grocery-crud

I have 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_patient` (
    id_patient      INTEGER     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name            VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT "not available",
    att1            VARCHAR(5 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT "att1",
    att2            VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT "att2",
    att3            VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT "att3",
    CONSTRAINT `uc_Info_patient` UNIQUE (`id_patient`)           
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_patient_medicine` ( 
    id_patient_medicine INTEGER     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_patient          INTEGER     NOT NULL,
    name_medicine       VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT "", 
    dosis               VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT "",         
    start_date          timestamp   NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    treatment            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT "", 
    times_per_day       VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT "",    
    CONSTRAINT fk_ID_Patient_Medicine  FOREIGN KEY (id_patient)   REFERENCES `tbl_patient`(id_patient)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

As you can see table patient_medicine is the intermediate table of between tbla_medicines, and table patient.

Now I want to consult all data from tbl_patient_medicine with grocery crud [like in this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5960f/4)

supossing I pass the id in the uri (in the example will be id_patient=1)
I have

```
public function details_medication($my_id = 0)
{   
  try{
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->where('id_patient',$my_id);
    $crud->set_table('tbl_patient_medicine');


        //HOW TO DO IT? 
        $crud->set_relation('id_patient', 'tbl_patient', 'id_patient');


    $output = $crud->render();
        $this->_output($output); 

     }catch(Exception $e){
    show_error($e->getMessage().' --- '.$e->getTraceAsString());
     }      
}
```

SO I have tried different ways but got errors like this:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1052

Column 'id_patient' in where clause is ambiguous

SELECT `tbl_patient_medicine`.*, j7a675883.id_patient AS s7a675883 
FROM (`tbl_patient_medicine`) 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_patient` as j7a675883 
ON `j7a675883`.`id_patient` = `tbl_patient_medicine`.`id_patient` WHERE `id_patient` = '1' LIMIT 25
```

Line Number: 87

Comment: I am not sure, I guess its the primary key thats causing the problem.Try using different column name, try this , $crud->set_relation('id_patient', 'tbl_patient', 'name'); Just try n temme the o/p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did your example:

Controller:

```
function medicine() 

{
     $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

     $crud->set_table('tbl_patient_medicine');
     $crud->required_fields('id_patient','name_medicine','dosis','start_date','treatment','time_per_day');
     $crud->columns('id_patient','name_medicine','dosis','start_date','treatment','time_per_day');
     $crud->fields('id_patient','name_medicine','dosis','start_date','treatment','time_per_day');

     $crud->set_relation('id_patient','tbl_patient','name');

     $output = $crud->render();  

     $this->_example_output($output); 
}
```

It works!

**Edited:**

```
$crud->set_relation('id_patient','tbl_patient','{name},  {att1},  {att2},  {att3}');
```

Comment: could you plese post complete code, as I think I am doing something very wrong?

Comment: Here you have the complete controller. Test it, and it will works.

Comment: Ok, I have tried it and it works, but is there a way to get all fields of `tbl_patient` like, ID, NAME, att1,att2,att and all fields of  `tbl_patient_medicine`? In your solution I can only get in the field ID the name of patient, how to get all fields from `tbl_patient`

Answer (score -1):

Try by changing WHERE j7a675883.`id_patient`

Comment: well, I can´t because that is autogenerated by grocerycrud